# ReactiveMongo: How to convert BSON returned by FindAndModify to JSON

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Here below is the code for updating a document with Mongo's `FindAndModify`:

```
val selector = BSONDocument("id" -> "1234")
val modifier = BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("email" -> "new@domain.com"))    

ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.command(FindAndModify(
   collection.name,
   selector,
   Update(modifier, false),
   false,
   None
 )).transform(
   success => success.map { s =>
     // doesn't work...
     Json.fromJson[Seq[JsValue]](toJson(s)).map(for (item <- _) yield item).get
   }.getOrElse(List[JsValue]()),
   failure => failure match {
     case e: LastError => DaoServiceException(e.message, Some(DATABASE_ERROR))
   } 
)
```

In the `success` block I'm trying to convert the returned `BSONDocument` collection into a `JsValue` collection... but it doesn't work and the resulting `JsValue` collection is always empty (I've verified the `BSONDocument` collection returned by the command and I confirm it is **non-empty**). Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps try using the [BSON Handler implicits](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/modules/reactivemongo/bsonhandlers.scala) from Play-ReactiveMongo to convert from `BSONDocument` to `JsObject`? I imagine that they would be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BSON handlers implicits (suggested in comment) might not work because FindAndModify command has a strict signature to return `Option[BSONDocument]`

```
FindAndModify extends BSONCommandResultMaker[Option[BSONDocument]]
```

given the returned result is of `Future[Option[BSONDocument]]` type

you can import the json formats

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.BSONFormats._
```

and apply

```
result.map(docOpt => docOpt.map(d => Json.toJson(d)))
```

on result, or call the conversion directly

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.BSONFormats

result.map(docOpt => docOpt.map(d =>
  BSONFormats.BSONDocumentFormat.writes(d).as[JsObject]))
```

Comment: I was able to perform an atomic multi-update... but the result always contains one object instead of a collection containing ALL the old values. If the command updates two documents, then I'd expect a BSONArray containing two entries... or am I wrong? I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: I think I understand now... I thought FindAndModify is able to update multiple documents at once... but actually it doesn't. It just updates the first document that matches the selection criteria. What a pity :-(

Comment: Now it is deprecated, instead: `import reactivemongo.play.json.BSONFormats.BSONDocumentFormat`