# How to print contents of a BSONDocument

Tags: scala, playframework, bson, reactivemongo

I am tyring to implement CRUD operations using reactiveMongo, and here is my find function from a tutorial online.

```
def findTicker(ticker: String) = {
    val query = BSONDocument("firstName" -> ticker)
    val future = collection.find(query).one

    future.onComplete {
      case Failure(e) => throw e
      case Success(result) => {
        println(result)

      }
    }
  }
```

However I am getting this Result:

`Some(BSONDocument(<non-empty>))`

How can I actually see an actual readable JSON data I am looing for:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("569914557b85c62b49634c1d"), "firstName" : "Stephane", "lastName" : "Godbillon", "age" : 29 }`

Comment: `BSONDocument.pretty(bsonDoc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS ANSWER IS BASED ON [@Barry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112665/barry) PREVIOUS ANSWER BEFORE THE EDITS:

I got it to work using the play-reactivemongo updated version:
`"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9",`

Now,

```
result.map { data =>
          println(Json.toJson(data))
        }
```

returns what I want:

`{"_id":0,"name":"MongoDB","type":"database","count":1,"info":{"x":203,"y":102}}`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without playframework module. There is a `pretty` function specialy for this:

```
result match{
  case Some(document) => println(BSONDocument.pretty(document))
  case None => println("No document")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**With Play-ReactiveMongo**

So you have a few options. It looks like your using the Play framework and then I assume Play-ReactiveMongo Plugin. If thats the case checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666105/reactivemongo-how-to-convert-bson-returned-by-findandmodify-to-json) Its a bit different but I think you can re-use the ideas from the submitted answer.

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.BSONFormats._
```

and then in your success case

```
case Success(result) => {
 result.map { data =>
  Json.toJson(data)
}
```

There are other options to convert BSONDocuments to JSON but Play-ReactiveMongo makes things easier.

**Without the Play-ReactiveMongo plugin** you will need to tell ReactiveMongo how to Write and Read your data. To do this ReactiveMongo uses BSONDocumentReaders & BSONDocumentWriters. They do provide a Macro to generate these for most classes [this link has more info](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/bson/typeclasses.html)

```
import reactivemongo.bson._

//lets say your domain/case class is called Person
implicit val personHandler:BSONHandler[BSONDocument,Person] = Macros.handler[Person]
```

A BSONHandler gathers both BSONReader and BSONWriter traits and you can place this implicit in Persons companion object.

ReactiveMongos `one` method is generic on the type of entity it is looking for and takes an implicit reader for your entity.

```
  def one[T](readPreference: ReadPreference)(implicit reader: Reader[T], ec:    ExecutionContext): Future[Option[T]]
```

So in this example it would use the Reader generated from the Macro above to return a `Future[Option[Person]]` instead of `Future[Option[BSONDocument]]`. Then you can use the Play JSON to write your domain in JSON

For full disclosure you can write your own customer writers rather than use the Macro and these end up being similar to writing Play JSON writers and readers

Comment: Thought of one thing let me know the version of Play you are using their JSON library changed in recent versions so Play-ReactiveMongo has been updated. The import above would be for older version of Play

Comment: I am using the reactivemongo driver and not the play moduel :(

Comment: My PLAY version is 2.4.6

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think this is kind of complicated. Your previous example using the play-reactivemongo made more sense. Do you think I can use the previous example with the Play version I have?

Comment: looks like you got it feel free to get in touch if you have further quesitons/comments